# How can I delete a bundle identifier managed by Xcode 8.1?

Tags: xcode, xcode8, code-signing, app-id

I would like to move my Xcode project to a different Team/Developer Account and use the same App/Bundle ID. I have tried to create the App ID in Apple Developer Centre on the new Account however I get an error that the App ID is not available, which is to be expected.

My Xcode project has `Automatically manage signing` ticked. I cannot see the Bundle Idenitifier of the project within the list of App IDs within the Developer Centre of the Account that the project is currently associated with. Where are Xcode managed App IDs stored and how do I delete one?

I have definitely managed to do this before Automatically managed signing was introduced, simply by deleting the App ID from the original iOS Developer Account and manually reregistering it on the new account.

Edit: Just to be clear- the App has not been submitted to the App Store, it is still in the Development stage.

Comment: Why not just change the bundle ID?

Comment: That is an option however we used the actual bundle ID we would have used on the new (client) account while the App was being developed using our company dev account. Regardless, I find it odd that Xcode managed App IDs aren't amendable anywhere.

Comment: What happens if you turn off Automatically manage signing?

Comment: I did try that, I still can't see the App ID in Dev centre. I've a feeling this is something entirely unrelated. Will leave details in a comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: OK. I think that because of the odd circumstances by which you have acquired this app, you have no choice but to change the bundle ID.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I manage to do that is to contact the customer support (Apple Developer Program Support), after few days and few back and forth they finally deleted the bundle id from my Personal Team and I was able to add it to my Developer Program (Agent) profile. I know this is not ideal but at least if you really want to use the same Bundle ID it worked for me.

**Remember**
I accidentally registered my app ID into my non-paid apple account. That's why I had to contact customer support otherwise you can just delete it from [developer portal](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Faccount%2F&rv=1)

Answer (score 1):

I am able to see all Xcode managed app ids in my developer account and am able to delete them from my account.

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com
2. Click on Account at the top
3. Sign In to your developer account
4. Click on "Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles"
5. Navigate to App IDs (under the Identifiers section on the left of the screen)

   [image: app ids]
6. Find and click on the app id you want to delete. The app id will expand to show more information. (if the bundle id is `com.myapps.mytestapp` then the name in the developer portal will be "XC com myapps mytestapp")
7. Tap on "Edit" at the bottom of the app id's section. You'll be navigated to a new page.

[image: edit]

8. Tap "Delete" at the bottom of the page.

[image: delete]

9. You'll be prompted to make sure you want to delete the app id. Hit "Delete" again and you're done.

[image: delete for real]

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer because you are technically correct. However, I've a feeling the App ID has been reserved by another development team who worked on this App previously. Our client lost faith in them and came to us to develop the App instead. 

It's odd that we were able to use the App ID in our xcode project though. The App ID is definitely not in the list of App ID's in our Developer Account.

Comment: The project is actually using a wildcard App ID despite us having entered a Bundle ID in the field.

Comment: @remondo I've nothing against this answer but in my opinion you shouldn't be marking it correct. The fact is that _your_ app ID does _not_ appear in the list at the Member Center and that's the problem. The answer does not at all address that fact — indeed, it ignores it.

Comment: Any idea how we can delete in build like edit and check box at each lsited item